# Grails HasMany on Long

Tags: grails, criteria, grails-domain-class

I have an class with an hasMany on a Long:

```
 class Test {
   static hasMany = [longList:Long]
}
```

I want to filter on longList with Criteria:

```
Test.createCriteria().list{
        'in'('longList',[Long.valueOf('1')])
}
```

I get an **SQLException**: *No value specified for parameter 1.*

The SQL looks like this:

```
select * from test this_ where this_.id in (?)
```

i tried things like:

```
    createAlias('labours', 'l')
 eq('l',Long.valueOf(filter.labourId)) )
```

or

```
eq('labours.value', Long.valueOf(filter.labourId))
```

But i can't get it working.

For a workaround i would make another domain Class:

```
class Test {
     statis hasMany=[longList:TestLongList]
}
class TestLongList{ 
   Long longListItem
   static belongsto = [test:Test]
}
```

This should be working but i must always create an TestLongList Instance if I create an Test Object, so the code would turn from:

```
test.addToLongList(Long.valueOf('22'))
```

to

```
TestLongList tll = new TestLongList
tll.test= test
tll.longListitem = Long.valueOf('22')
tll.save()
test.addToLongList(tll)
```

Is there a way to stay with the Long-List without HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite the criteria to look like this:

```
Test.createCriteria().list{
   createAlias('longList', 'l')
   'in' ('l.elements', [1L])
}
```

This boils down to the property name under which Hibernate stores collection (`elements`).